# Few basic questions on combinational logic

Tags: digital-logic

I'm little confused in the topic of Decoders.
For example when a question asks: 
Build 4-to-16 decoder, using 2-to-4 decoder.

Does that mean the first decoder has 4 inputs and 16 outputs ? If so why the answer to this question has for the first decoder a 2 inputs and only 4 outputs ( that connected later to 4 decoders and each has 2 inputs and 4 outputs)

Lastly, how can I build 8-to-16 decoder (Active low)?

Comment: Do your 2-to-4 decoders have an active-low enable? (hint)

Comment: Is that a typo in your last line? You're not really asking how to build an 8-to-16 decoder are you? (4-to-16 right?)

Answer (score 1):

> Does that mean the first decoder has 4 inputs and 16 outputs ?

No, it means the whole circuit you are designing has 4 inputs and 16 outputs.

> If so why the answer to this question has for the first decoder a 2 inputs and only 4 outputs

Because your instructions are to build your circuit "using 2-to-4 decoder[s]". You need to use 2-to-4 decoders as the components in the circuit you are designing.

Answer (score 0):

To design active Low replace the And gates By NAND's in active high decoder.
If you are truly asking about 4-to-16 bit active decoder then it can be design like this one,
[image]

Still if you need to work on 8-to-16 bit then you can preferably make an combinational circuitdepending on the p.s.